# Java Library for ZPL Code Interpretation to Build a ZPL Viewer

Tags: java, interpreter, zpl

I'm currently working on a project to develop a ZPL Viewer in Java, aimed at rendering ZPL label designs and providing a user-friendly interface. To achieve this, I am in search of a Java library or framework capable of interpreting ZPL code and converting it into Java objects or a similar data format. This interpretation step is crucial for rendering the ZPL label designs effectively.

While exploring potential solutions, I have come across the GitHub repository w3blogfr/zebra-zpl. However, upon closer examination, it seems that this repository lacks the interpreter functionality I need for my project.

Given this context, I have a few questions:

1. Can anyone recommend a Java library or framework that can effectively interpret ZPL code and convert it into Java objects or data structures suitable for rendering ZPL label designs?
2. If such a library doesn't exist, I'm also considering the option of writing my own ZPL code interpreter. Are there any resources or best practices that you can recommend for building a ZPL interpreter in Java?

I appreciate any insights, recommendations, or guidance on this matter. Your assistance will be valuable in making this ZPL Viewer project a success. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Questions asking us to [recommend or find a book](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.

Comment: In the link it says explicitly "3. Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it." which is what I mentioned above. Unfortunately even with the changes it still is a request for recommendations.

Comment: I once wrote such an interpreter for a small subset of ZPL commands in Delphi: https://github.com/TheDelphiCoder/Zebra

Comment: Thank you; it's fascinating how you've tackled this. Could you share a sample output you've obtained from the interpreter? Based on what I've observed, this should be capable of offering a preview of the ZPL Code, correct?